# Is it possible to define a type from an array object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an array

```
const a = [
  {
     name: 'n1',
     text: 't1',
  },
  {
     name: 'n2',
     text: 't2',
  },
  {
     name: 'n3',
     text: 't3',
  },
]
```

I want to define a type `type t = 'n1' | 'n2' | 'n3'` from array `a`, is it possible in typescript?

Answer (score 4):

If you define your array with a *const assertion* (`as const`) then you can use `typeof a[number]["name"]`:

```js
const a = [
  {
     name: 'n1',
     text: 't1',
  },
  {
     name: 'n2',
     text: 't2',
  },
  {
     name: 'n3',
     text: 't3',
  },
] as const;

type Names = typeof a[number]["name"];
```

Here is a [working repl with the type definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gKBjA3hzmxwC2ApgFwwDkYAjBQDS55TEAeU5FUtDmAvj9kb4iZSmABM9ITGZsOUSQP64ceYSQ5gAzFLUzW7SlB1KGAXXgQYoSFADcaNFACeAB2IwAciKvIX7kAAzeBQwAFdCACNiACczFAAiAhIEszsgA).

Comment: Is there a way to apply 'as const' after the fact, like on the same statement as the typeof ( it doesn't seem to work, but I'm wondering if there is a workaround for that if you can't modify the original data) ?